# docker-machine AWS can't create machine Error checking and/or regenerating the certs

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

All of a sudden I can't create new machines with docker machine on AWS. I can connect to old machines just fine, but when trying to create new ones I get this output:

`Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with ubuntu(upstart)...
Installing Docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Checking connection to Docker...
Error creating machine: Error checking the host: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "x.x.155.174:2376": read tcp x.x.x.x:xxxxx->x.x.155.174:2376: read: connection reset by peer
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop running containers.`

I'm using this AMI `ami-5e63d13e`

Anyone have a workaround for this? Been stuck for hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Docker, fixed with the latest release (0.12.1): https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4156